# What is "System.Windows.Navigation" assembly in Windows Form Applications

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, navigation, browser, windows

i am trying to add these codes :

```
public partial class My_SyS : Form
{
    List<Uri> HistoryStack;
    int HistoryStack_Index;
    bool fromHistory;

    public Sisi_Start()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HistoryStack = new List<Uri>();
        HistoryStack_Index = 0;
        fromHistory = false;
        webBrowser_main.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser_main_Navigated);
        updateNavButtons();
    }

    ....
```

and here is `webBrowser_main_Navigated` event :

```
private void webBrowser_main_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
```

i got the **error** below :

```
The type or namespace name 'Navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

which assembly should i use for the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to  [`System.Windows.Navigation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the **PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)** Assembly